# c++ std::cout unespected output

Tags: c++, std, cout

Hi I'm writing some debug output with std::cout with this code:

EDIT: as suggested I added a std::flush on each cout and an std::endl on each iteration

```
int
    index = 0,
    size = vector.size();
for (iterate trough a vector)
{
    std::cout << "Actual element: " << index+1 << "/" << size << std::flush;
    ...
    if (bad element)
    {
        std::cout << " -> Bad Element" << std::flush;
    }
    std::cout << std::endl;
}
```

The bad element string appear only after the successive element, why?
What am I missing?

Thanks a lot!

Comment: Are you sure to enter in the `if` condition ?

Comment: Yes, it actually print the bad element string. I wrote it in pseudo code because the condition and the iteration weren't the problem

Comment: Please show us the real code as the problem is most likely there.

Answer (score 1):

You should have a `std::cout << std::flush` (or `std::cout << std::endl`) in your `for` loop which is always done (even without bad elements), or at least after your `for` loop....

Comment: +1 Or just use `std::cerr`, especially nice if stdout is redirected and you still want a console-debug log.

Comment: Or even `std::clog` maybe?

Comment: But if I use the flush it doesn't print anything on output until it reach an endl, why?

Comment: @BasileStarynkevitch Both write to stderr, but `cerr` is unbuffered (so each output to it is visible immediately), whereas `clog` is buffered (so you would still need to flush)